# what is the best way to update 2 tables via data entry form in access 2007 database?

Tags: database-design, ms-access

I have a database with more than 500.000 records, I am using Table_a to Accessing the files by the ID number,Name, Date, Address, Tel, .....
And then I used Table_b to archive files and locate the position where should I keep that file, just by entering the ID.
Is there any way to update the Database to have it all in one action?
I mean after Accessing the file, I should have a check box, or a drop drown list to move the record directly to the Archive at the same time?

Comment: Your question does not supply enough information on the flow of your database. which files are you tring to archive?
is archiving necessary?
"Is there any way to update the Database to have it all in one action?"
What do you exactly mean by this?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear but I want to give some suggestions about the errors:

1.you should use specific tables for archive and other details.

2.you should maintain specific DNS servers on ODBCcad for regular data and archive files.

these two points would certainly help you a lot.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your questions is a little foggy
2. You don't mention how the archiving process works
3. You're basically asking about a feature on the User Interface side ... not on the DB side.

---

In the first use case, you (or the application) do a **select** to retrieve some metadata about a file;
In the second one, you enter an ID (**select** query) and the application does the archiving (**insert** statement into table_b);

What exactly do you need to automate here ?